# Javascript query string swap

Tags: javascript

I have a script that accepts a query string as a parameter.  The script looks for the supplied string (which is intentionally written on the page) and replaces it with the supplied query string in the url.  This works perfectly on the home page of a website like so "www.website.com/?city="foo"  but the script will not do the swap when i try to run it on an inner page meaning any url that has an additional level of depth e.g. www.wbsite.com/page/?city=bar

I cannot identify what is causing this in the function.

The result is supposed to be this:

I define what the function looks for like "We do service" (this is written on the page somewhere)

I supply the query parameter in the URL: www.website.com/?city=city

The script looks for this hook and replaces it with my supplied string as follows:

"We do service in" + QS.city + " "

The result being: "We do service in city."

```
(function(){var QS = function () {   
    var x = {};   
    var y = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var z = y.split("&");

    for (var i=0;i<z.length;i++) {
       var a = z[i].split("=");

       if (typeof x[a[0]] === "undefined") {
           x[a[0]] = decodeURIComponent(a[1]).replace(/\+/gi, ' ');
       } else if (typeof x[a[0]] === "string") {
           var b = [ x[a[0]],decodeURIComponent(a[1]).replace(/\+/gi, ' ')];x[a[0]] = b;
       } else {
           x[a[0]].push(decodeURIComponent(a[1]).replace(/\+/gi, ' '));
   }
} 
return x;
}();

if (QS.hasOwnProperty('city')) {    
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('We Build Powerful', 'We Build Powerful Websites in ' + QS.city + ' ');
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Build a Stronger Brand', 'Build a Stronger Brand in ' + QS.city + '');
}
})();
```

Comment: Please format your code, the indentation is all messed up and it's hard to read. You'll have better luck getting help if you can clean this up first.

Comment: My apologies, i've edited the code, should be easier to read now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are splitting code at '&' which is leaving the first array element with your entire url. The cleanest and most intuitive way I'll suggest is to simply take a substring after your first '?'.

In your case simply use this before your loop start:

> `var x = {}; 
>       var y = window.location.search.substring(1);
>       y = y.substring(y.lastIndexOf('?') + 1);
>       var z = y.split("&");`

Comment: sadly that didnt work, i notice that the parameters in the replace method are transposed, which does not happen in the home page

Comment: Ummm I tried this solution myself before posting it. Anyway, You have a solution. That's good

Comment: Im not sure how it worked, It is not working for me - i get this back document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('Powerful boston ', 'Powerful ' + QS.city + ' '); - my parameter is ?city=boston , it somehow is injected into the first paramter of the replace method

Comment: I am still not getting you. Can you give me an example of document.body.innerHTML which you are using ?

Comment: document.body.innerHTML.replace('Powerful  ', 'Powerful ' + QS.city + ' '); I am looking for the word Powerful on the website and want to replace it with "Powerful " + QS.city - which is my parameter,  However, instead of that happening the city is injected into the first parameter of replace('Powerful boston ', 'Powerful ' + QS.city + ' '); - it is not supposed to go there when this works this does not happen, im not sure how else to explain the behavior makes no sense to me im not asking for the city to be displayed there but it is ( in inspect element)

Comment: Can you check if there is some error in your console ? Might be a case with you other code. Or Is it like the first instance gets replaced but not all ?

Comment: It would be quite helpful if you can share an instance of your innerHTML here. What is the InnerHTML and what you finally expect it as an output

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171268/discussion-between-user2035552-and-parth-mahajan).